# Когда использовать Model а когда ViewModel в ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Сабж.
Для примера, есть у меня модель User, в представлении мне нужно вывести инфу о юзере, и этой модели мне хватит.
Но мб правильно будет все таки создать UserViewModel и использовать ее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewModel создаётся для View. Если вьюшка у вас UpdateUserView то логично создать для нее UpdateUserViewModel, если UserInfoView то UserInfoViewModel, а Model это DTO (Data Transfer Object) для базы данных, я так понимаю у Вас. UpdateUserViewModel в общем случае не обязан совпадать с UserInfoViewModel, поскольку для представления Update могут понадобиться также списки (Country, Gender,..) и вовсе не нужны в UserInfoViewModel. Это и создаёт у вас проблемы в понимании MVC. ViewModel может компоноваться из нескольких DTO и содержать поля необходимые для конкретной View. Это все и контролируется контроллером.

**Upd**. Конечно порой возникает желание использовать использовать User в качестве ViewModel и не использовать конкретную. Но тогда добавляя либо изменяя User нужно будет заботиться о местах где User использовался в чистом виде, что может порождать проблемы в будущем. Как пример добавить поля login password могут непреднамеренно опубликовать приватные данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, стало на много понятнее!

Comment: Да не вопрос, всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: Ничего не понял, откуда vm в mvc? Это же не mvvm.

Comment: @aepot это модель. Автор всего лишь путает определения. Называй Model переданную во View - ModelView и все будет совместимо с MVC